# How can I detect subnets?

Tags: network

Given a WAN, which is connected to the internet via a single exit point.
Inside this WAN, I don't want to have any subnet structures. 
Every user gets his own access point, which he can expand via switches. 
The use of routers and especially WiFi routing is strictly prohibited.

How can I find out if a user is setting up WiFi or is creating a subnet?

Comment: It sounds like you meant LAN instead of WAN?

Comment: No, it is a WAN. The network access points are spread over more then 100 km distance. Why the question?

Comment: @user1786193 Technically that's a WAN, but most people assume you're referring to LAN as the inside network and WAN as the Internet - so, with that usage, your network would be the LAN. (I might call it a MAN, but 100km seems a bit big for that.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible. The only way you can detect if someone setup a router with NAT function is to analyze the hardware addresses (MAC) of the endpoints. But the hardware address can be changed so that not very reliable solution.

Another way to detect WiFi networks is by physically move around in the area of the network and scan for WiFi networks with your phone or computer.

Why do you want to forbid routers? I can understand that you want to forbid WiFi access points, but why wired routers?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to expand such a network with routers. 
First time I used a WiFi router and the second time I tried it without WiFi. Both times the access point was closed and I had to request a new one. Not  a big deal.  
But I don't understand how it can be determined, if somebody uses routers.

Comment: I guess you don't have changed the MAC address of the router. Or maybe they have done a portscan found your remote administration webinterface for your router. Maybe you pluged the network cable in the LAN port instead of the WAN and the router had an active DHCP server that broadcastet DHCP responses. Who knows, it's hard to tell with so little information.